# Websocket on Docker with nginx

Tags: docker, go, nginx, websocket

I am trying to build a service with two parts: a backend and a frontend. Both are on a different docker container and are communicating through the docker-compose configuration and a nginx container.

For https access, everything's good, but when I am trying to work with websocket, I have an upgrade error, even if the Nginx configuration got this information

Error message : `websocket: the client is not using the websocket protocol:  'upgrade' token not found in 'Connection' header`

I am using a `fasthttp` and `fasthttp/websocket` for my Golang backend. The code is working on localhost (no nginx configuration), but the combinaison of Docker + nginx seems to break something.
The front-end works with `react` and is a simple `let socket = new WebSocket(`wss.mydomain.com/ws/uploadPicture/`);`

EDIT :

- when using `ctx.Request.Header.ConnectionUpgrade()` just before `upgrader.Upgrade`, the result is `true`, but `ctx.Response.Header.ConnectionUpgrade()` is false

Thank you !

---

*Golang Backend*

```golang
var upgrader = websocket.FastHTTPUpgrader{
    ReadBufferSize:  1024,
    WriteBufferSize: 1024,
    CheckOrigin: func(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) bool {
        return true
    },
}
func    InitRouter() func(*fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    router := fasthttprouter.New()

    router.GET("/ws/uploadPicture/", doWS)

    return router.Handler
}
func    doWS(ctx *fasthttp.RequestCtx) {
    err := upgrader.Upgrade(ctx, func(conn *websocket.Conn) {
        //SHOULD DO STUFF
    })
    if (err != nil) {
        logs.Error(err.Error()) //HIT THIS ERROR
        return
    }
}

...
fasthttp.ListenAndServe(`:8000`, InitRouter())
```

*Nginx.conf*

```
#############################################################################
## NGINX CONFIGURATION FOR THE WEBAPP
#############################################################################
upstream webapp {
    server webapp:3000;
    keepalive 4;
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_pass http://webapp;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}

#############################################################################
## NGINX CONFIGURATION FOR THE PROXY
#############################################################################
upstream proxy {
    server proxy:8000;
    keepalive 4;
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name api.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' "$http_origin";
        add_header 'Access-Control-Allow-Credentials' true;
        proxy_pass http://proxy;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_redirect off;
    }
}


#############################################################################
## NGINX CONFIGURATION FOR THE PROXY
#############################################################################
upstream proxyws {
    server proxy:8000;
    keepalive 4;
}
server {
    listen [::]:443 ssl;
    listen 443 ssl;

    server_name wss.mydomain.com;

    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/fullchain.pem;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/mydomain.com/privkey.pem;
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf;
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem;

    location / {
        proxy_http_version 1.1;
        proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Connection upgrade;
        proxy_set_header Host $host;
        proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
        proxy_redirect off;
        proxy_pass http://proxyws;
    }

}
```

*Docker-compose*

```
  #############################################################################
  ## IMAGE FOR THE PROXY
  #############################################################################
  proxy:
    container_name: proxy
    build: ./src/Proxy
    restart: always
    env_file: .env
    ports:
      - "8000:8000"

  #############################################################################
  ## IMAGE FOR THE WEBAPP
  #############################################################################
  webapp:
    container_name: webapp
    build: ./src/Webapp
    restart: always
    volumes:
      - ./src/Webapp:/home/app
      - /home/app/.next
      - /home/app/node_modules
    ports:
      - 3000:3000

  #############################################################################
  ## IMAGE THE NGINX & CERTBOT FOR REVERSE PROXY
  #############################################################################
  nginx: 
    image: nginx:latest
    container_name: nginx
    volumes:
      - ./data/nginx:/etc/nginx/conf.d
      - ./data/certbot/conf:/etc/letsencrypt
      - ./data/certbot/www:/var/www/certbot
    ports:
      - 80:80
      - 443:443
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out it's not an issue with Nginx/Docker, but with the http package in golang that is supposed to upgrade the connection.
I was using [fasthttp](https://github.com/valyala/fasthttp) with [fasthttp/websocket](https://github.com/fasthttp/websocket) wich is supposed to work, but which does not in a docker container.

I tried to switch to [httprouter](https://github.com/julienschmidt/httprouter) with the official (not fork as for the fasthttp ones) [gorilla/websocket](http://github.com/gorilla/websocket) and the connection successfully upgrade.

Gonna check where the issue come from !

Answer (score 2):

I'm the maintainer of websocket package for fasthttp. The issue is fixed on master branch.

Downdload it with:

```sh
go get github.com/fasthttp/websocket@master
```

And try again, please.

If the issue continue, please open an issue in https://github.com/fasthttp/websocket/issues

Soon, I will release a new version.

Answer (score 0):

I believe `upgrade` should be a string:

```
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
```

Comment: I tries it, unfortunately it's not the solution for this issue